# How to reference and manipulate a single entity in a sprite group in pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I have several groups to sort my variables (i.e. - `enemy_group = pygame.sprite.Group()`). However, I don't know how to "get" a single enemy and move it around (and, ideally, attack the player). Could someone help me do this?

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # insert pygame.Surface variables
    
    def update(self):
        # move entity accordingly (which is what I'm trying to do)

# game loop
enemy_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemy_group.update()
enemy_group.draw(screen)
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Please elaborate what you're trying to do (your final goals) and how the game objects should behave, what you've tried yet and provide a code example if you can.

Comment: I don't think sprite groups support any kind of indexing so you can't really "get" a sprite in it. What I use to do was iterate through the group and perform action depending on conditions. For a shoot'em up you could set a timer and have a firing rate, check for it, and perform attacks when the fire rate time has been exceeded.

Comment: Could we see a little code to get started? We can't just 'guess' as to what you might already have written, so we can really visualize the code/your problem.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to achieve. By which criteria do you pick the sprite? Should it be a random sprite or one that is close to the enemy, and how should it behave in contrast to the other enemy sprites? Do you maybe want to implement anything like a view radius in which the enemies can see the player?

Comment: Ah, sorry. All enemy sprites should be stationary and those on the bottom row should be moved first. Once an sprite has been "killed", the sprite above that becomes eligible to be "activated". When activated, sprites should move (ideally) toward the player than move sharply away and back again. When it moves off the screen, reset its position and pick another sprite.

Edit: Sprites are arranged on the screen in 4 rows of 8

Comment: Did you get this resolved? If so, how? I'm looking to do something similar with my Alien Invasion game. I currently have a group of 4 rows of 8 aliens which move together. I'd like to randomly pick a single alien from the group and have it attack my ship.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilities. A [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) is iterable. Hence you can go through the elements in a `for`-loop:

```py
for enemy in enemy_group:
    # [...]
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`sprites()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.sprites) method:

> Return a list of all the Sprites this group contains.

Get a list of *Sprites* and access them by subscription:

```py
emeny_list = enemy_group.sprites()
enemy_1 = emeny_list[0]
```